# How can I put the subject of the students by their Year Level?

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

**student_table**

```
INSERT INTO `student_table` (`student_id`, `name`, `year_level`, `section`) 
VALUES (1001, 'Paul', '4', 'A');    
INSERT INTO `student_table` (`student_id`, `name`, `year_level`, `section`)
 VALUES (1002, 'Jake', '5', 'A');    
INSERT INTO `student_table` (`student_id`, `name`, `year_level`, `section`) 
VALUES (10005, 'John', '4', 'A');
```

**subject_table**

```
INSERT INTO `subject_table` (`sub_id`, `sub_code`, `sub_name`, `year_level`) 
VALUES ('1', '103', 'English', '4');    
INSERT INTO `subject_table` (`sub_id`, `sub_code`, `sub_name`, `year_level`)
 VALUES ('2', '104', 'Math', '5');
```

**year_table**

```
INSERT INTO `year_table` (`year_id`, `year_level`) VALUES ('10', '4');    
INSERT INTO `year_table` (`year_id`, `year_level`) VALUES ('11', '5');
```

is this possible guys? I just need an brief explanation how can I insert the subjects of the students by their own year level?

Jake must have a subject Math &
John & Paul must have a subject English  is this possible guys?

**Expected Output**:

[image: Expected Output]

Comment: What is your question? Please show the result that you want for this sample data.

Comment: @GMB pls see this here is the expected output sir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to want a `join`:

```
select st.*, su.subname
from student_table st 
inner join subject_table su on su.year_level = st.year_level
```

It doesn't look like you need `year_table` to produce the results you want.

Comment: @Sanity: that's an *alias* for `student_table` in the query. Aliases are an important part of the SQL language.